# Show columns from the record on click in the same page - laravel

Tags: php, laravel, view, laravel-blade

In the **controller** I take all the records which I serve and send them to the view:

```
$projects = Project::where('column', '=', $column)->get();
return View::make('home')->with('projects', $projects);
```

In the **view** I show all record with @foreach (blade):

```
@foreach ($projects as $project)  
    <a href="#">{{ $project['column'] }}<a>
@endforeach
```

It is created a list with all records but **only one column is shown** ('column').

I would like to **show the other columns from the record when I click it**.

Example:

```
<a href="#">Name One</>
<a href="#">Name Two</>  <!-- I clicked this --> 
<a href="#">Name Three</>

<ul>
  <li>Name Two</li>
  <li>Other column Name Two</li>
  <li>Another column Name Two</li>
  <li>More column Name Two</li>
</ul>
```

Thanks!

Comment: I solved:  
     var allProjects = {!! $projects !!} 
But I will deepen ajax, thank you all

Answer (score 0):

Yes It is possible but for that you need to know ajax.
Do you Know Ajax??

Comment: Unfortunately no, according to your opinion, Ajax is the only possible solution?

Comment: If you want to really learn this i would be glad to help you.. I just need a friend who will learn and grow together with me, send me an email if you are interested easyvideotnt@gmail.com

Answer (score 0):

Brother your life will become lot more easier if learn ajax .
Trust me it's great.
there are so many ebooks which you will find on google very easily.

Comment: nearly Every website uses ajax